# Hibernate inheritence mapping with composite primary keys possible?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run code with the following constellation.

Setting class as base class:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(SettingId.class)
@Table(name = "setting")
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Setting implements Comparable<Setting> {
   
    @Id
    @Column(name = "key_", nullable = false, length = FieldConstants.SETTING_KEY_LENGTH)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SettingKey key;

    @Column(name = "value_", nullable = false, length = FieldConstants.SETTING_VALUE_LENGTH)
    private String value;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "type_", nullable = false, length = FieldConstants.SETTING_KEY_LENGTH)
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private SettingType type;
    ...
}
```

And another class that should inherit all the attributes from above:

```
@Entity
@IdClass(PersonSettingId.class)
@Table(name = "person_setting")
public class PersonSetting extends Setting {
    
    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_user"))
    private Person person;
    ...
}
```

The SettingId class is for the combined primary key for Setting (key and type).
The PersonSettingId extends SettingId and adds the person, which makes the three fields (key, type and person) as combined primary.

I get the following exception: UnionSubclass cannot be cast to class org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass

What do I habe to do to make this work?

Comment: Maybe a unique constraint over the 2 respectively 3 colums would do the job but then I have to introduce a numeric primary which is not really necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I introduced a numeric id now within setting class and use combined unique keys, e.g:

```
@Table(
name = "setting",
uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk_setting_type_key", columnNames = {   "type_", "key_" })
```

)

The same for the other class but with the additional person column.